# Cannot get value of switch from different VC Swift

Tags: swift, null, switch-statement

I want to access switch value with the code below. I get nil value. From the second View controller I get settings value to display content according to the value - englishRef.

SetConViewController is my settings view controller from where I want to get my value.

```
let languageSettingsRef = SetConvViewController()
var englishRef = ""
// Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
if languageSettingsRef.swithEnglish.isOn{
    englishRef = "yes"
}
```

In the View Controller below, there are switches for the settings

```
class SetConvViewController: UIViewController {
    var conversationSettingsReference: DatabaseReference!
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    var engS = "engS"
    var engGoster = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var swithEnglish: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let eng2 = defaults.value(forKey: engS) {
            swithEnglish.isOn = eng2 as! Bool
        }
    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBAction func switchEng(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        defaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: engS)
    }
}
```

I get nil when I want to access value from this class.

Comment: Why are you trying to access a view controller's switch? 1. You just created the view controller. It's views are not created yet. It hasn't been displayed yet. Accessing the switch is pointless. 2. You should never try to directly access another view controller's views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First It's nil because you don't load the VC from storyboard or xib

Second this line

```
let languageSettingsRef = SetConvViewController()
```

is not the presented one , so use delegate or any other observing technique to get current value of the presented VC

//

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController { 
     var setVc:SetConvViewController?
}
```

when you present `SettingsViewController` with with segue / push , set

```
settInstance.setVc = self
```

then ask the var about the switch value

```
if self.setVc.swithEnglish.isOn{
   englishRef = "yes"
}
```

Making the var as Bool is another better option